# What do xtest= and ytest= do in the randomForest algorithm in R?

Tags: r, random-forest

I am fitting a random forest and I have split my data into a training set and a test set using the following code:

`train <- sample( 1:nrow(Boston), (nrow(Boston))/2) )` 
EDIT: here, train is obviously just an index and thus the test set follows:

`testB <- Boston[-train,];  head(test);  length(test)`
The name of the response variable is medy and it is the fourteenth column.

I also have the following code for my random forest (actually I am bagging here because the total number of variables in my data set is 13):

`bag.boston1 <- randomForest(medv~., data=Boston, subset=train, mtry=13,
                            importance=TRUE, ytest=testB$medv, xtest= )`

Is my argument for the ytest= option correct? I assume so since that it is merely the response variable in the test data set.

Also, what argument should I use for the xtest= option?

One idea I had was to just eliminate the response variable from my test data set, thus creating a data frame only the predictors in the test data set, and then I could have the xtest argument be the resulting x matrix:

```
`x <- testB`

x[14] <- NULL  # because the 14th column is the response variable

bag.boston1 <- randomForest(medv~., data=Boston, subset=train, mtry=13,
                        importance=TRUE, ytest=testB$medv, xtest=x)
```

Comment: I would suggest to mark the answer below as the solution

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation of `randomForest`:

> If `xtest` is given, prediction of the test set is done “in place” as the trees are grown. If `ytest` is also given, and `do.trace` is set to some positive integer, then for every `do.trace` trees, the test set error is printed. Results for the test set is returned in the test component of the resulting `randomForest` object. For classification, the votes component (for training or test set data) contain the votes the cases received for the classes. If `norm.votes=TRUE`, the fraction is given, which can be taken as predicted probabilities for the classes.

It can be understood from here that only passing the response variable to `ytest` argument, doesn't change anything in the how the `randomForest` work.

If you want the `randomForest` function to make predictions "in place", i.e. when trees are being grown, you must pass the test data without the prediction variable to the `xtest` argument like this:

```
bag.boston1 <- randomForest(medv~., data=Boston, subset=train, mtry=13, importance=TRUE, 
                            xtest=subset(testB, select=-medv))
```

Prediction results can be accessed through: `bag.boston1$test$predicted`

Since you also have the response variable for the test data in this case, you can pass it using the `ytest` variable:

```
bag.boston2 <- randomForest(medv~., data=Boston, subset=train, mtry=13, importance=TRUE, 
                            xtest=subset(testB, select=-medv), ytest=testB$medv)
```

In this case, along with the predictions, we also get some additional values. They are, `mse` for mean square error and `rsq` for r-squared, both for each one of the trees grown in case of `regression`. And for `classification`, they are: `err.rate`, i.e. the test error rate for each tree, `confusion` for the confusion matrix and `votes` giving the vote count (or normalized vote count) for each of the output class.

All the above values can be accessed using: `bag.boston2$test`